# Find sibling element with class and replace html content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm not sure how to get the correct div to update and the correct link to click. I don't think I'm understanding the property usage for parent, sibling, find, prev, next, etc.

I'm submitting the form with AJAX and need to update the paragraph tag with class 'record-info' and click the link with class 'cancelas'.

The AJAX:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'editdelete'){
        var thisform = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                var replaceText = thisform.find('input[name="extraedit"]').val();
                console.log(thisform.parent().find('.record-info').html());
                thisform.parent().find('.record-info').html(replaceText);
                thisform.parent().find('.cancelas').click();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

`replaceText` displays the correct info in the console if I console.log it, but when I try to get the content of the 'record-info' paragraph, it displays as undefined. I've tried .parent().find(), .siblings(), .next(), .prev() and everything in between.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="catname record">
    <p class="record-info">Info is here</p>
    <p class="editmain">Edit</p>
    <p class="markmain">Mark</p>
    <form class="markas">FORM IS HERE</form>
    <div class="editas">
        <div>
            <form action="edit-delete.php" id="editdelete" method="post">
                <input name="extraedit" type="text">
            </form>
            <form action="edit-delete.php" id="editdelete" method="post">
                FORM CONTENT
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="cancelas">Cancel</p>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have several forms in your document with several controls having the same class ? cause else you could simply do `('.record-info').html(replaceText)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.record-info` is not a sibling of your forms, so just getting the parent and finding within that won't work.

Try `closest()`, which will traverse up the DOM tree until it finds a match (where parent only traverses one level, to the parent):

```
thisform.closest('.record').find('.record-info').html(replaceText);
```

The same goes for triggering your click:

```
thisform.closest('.record').find('.cancelas').click();
```

Note: I've used `.record` in `closest()` here because I'm assuming it is the common class across your 'records'. `.closest('.catname')` would work just as well in ***this*** case.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7P72/)